# Asp.net FindControl anywhere in under specific element

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, repeater

Let's say i have this markup structure

```
<asp:Repeater id="rptItems" datasource="getItemsList()" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rpAereos_ItemDataBound">
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Panel id="tableHolder" runat="server">
        <asp:table ID="TableHolded" runat="server">
                <asp:TableRow>
                        <asp:TableCell>
                            <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="panelToFind">Test</asp:Panel>
                        </asp:TableCell>
                    </asp:TableRow>
        </asp:table>
    </asp:Panel>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Now on ItemDataBound event I want to find the element *panelToFind*, but I don't want to go through all the elements to find this element like `e.Item.FindControl("tableHolder").FindControl("tableHolded").AReallyLongCallChainUntilMyItem ...` , I want to find anything under the *tableHolder* panel that has the id  *panelToFind*, How would my *ItemDataBound* event look?

I would like to know if something like: `e.Item.FindControl("tableHolder").FindAny("panelToFind")`

Comment: Have you considered recursive `FindControl`? ASP.NET does not provide it, but there are a lot of implementations out there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare an extension method like this:

```
public static class ControlExtensions
{

    public static IEnumerable<Control> GetEnumerableChildren(this Control control)
    {
        return control.Controls.Cast<Control>();
    }

    public static Control FindAny(this Control control, string id)
    {
        var result = control.GetEnumerableChildren().FirstOrDefault(c => c.ID == id);

        if (result != null)
            return result;

        return control.GetEnumerableChildren().Select(child => child.FindAny(id)).FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

Then do:

```
var foundControl = e.Item.FindControl("tableHolder").FindAny("panelToFind");
```

Note will return null if no control exists with that id.